# Mostrar u ocultar div y recargar la pagina

Tags: javascript, html, div

lo que quiero es que se pueda quedar marcado el checkbox y al refrescar la pagina no se reinicie la acción y no tenga que volver a marcar el check. Nota es mas de un checkbox pero solo pongo 1

```js
function mostrarInput() {
  elemento = document.getElementById("content");
  check = document.getElementById("check");

  if (check.checked) {
    elemento.style.display = 'block';
  } else {
    elemento.style.display = 'none';
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="form-check">
  <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="check" name="check" onchange="javascript:mostrarInput()" />
  <label class="form-check-label" for="gridCheck">
</div>
<div class="form-group col-md-6" id="content" style="display: none;">
  <input class="form-control" value="Contenido">
</div>
```

Comment: El valor del Checkbox debe guardarse en algun lugar para consultarlo al momento de re-cargar la pagina, te sugiero que lo guardes el localHost, es sencillo solo investiga como guardar y leer valores de localHost .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para lograr lo que quieres puedes utilizar [LocalStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API/Using_the_Web_Storage_API). LocalStorage te permite almacenar pares clave valor que se mantienen aun después de cerrar el navegador.

LocalStorage es en realidad muy sencillo de utilizar. Con `setItem()` almacenas los valores y con `getItem()` los obtienes.

En tu caso puedes utilizarlo de la siguiente manera.

```
const elemento = document.getElementById("content");

// Obtienes el valor almacenado en localStorage para 
// saber si mostrar o no el elemento.
const isChecked = localStorage.getItem('check')

if (isChecked == 'true') {
  elemento.style.display = 'block';
} else {
  elemento.style.display = 'none';
}

function mostrarInput() {

  check = document.getElementById("check");

  if (check.checked) {
    elemento.style.display = 'block';
  } else {
    elemento.style.display = 'none';
  }

  localStorage.setItem('check', check.checked);
}
```

> Nota: Ten en cuenta que los valores en localStorage se almacenan como string.

Comment: muchas gracias por tu ayuda, si se queda guardado el check al recargar la pagina pero el div no se muestra hasta que lo vuelva activar mediante el check

Comment: Tienes que obtener el div antes de mostrarlo. He corregido la respuesta, he declarado el div al principio del código.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes persistir este valor en el local storage o en las cookies.

Por ejemplo, cuando el usuario haga click en el botón puedes almacenar el resultado en:

```
function mostrarInput() {
    elemento = document.getElementById("content");
    check = document.getElementById("check");
    if (check.checked) {
        elemento.style.display = 'block';
    } else {
        elemento.style.display = 'none';
    }
    window.localStorage.setItem(check.id, check.cheked); // Here !!
}
```

Entonces al cargarse la pagina ejecuta una función que sea para setear los valores predefinidos.

```
const check = document.getElementById('check');
const value1 = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem(check.id))
check.checked = !!value1 ? value1 : false
```